# How often do PhD students from top universities go on the academic job market and fail to get a job?

Tags: job-search

I'm mainly interested in the field of computer science and how often students from top places simply fail to find academic jobs.

Comment: What definition of "top university" and "academic job" are you looking for here?

Comment: best info of this topic have ALUMNI organisations of that universities, or departments for student development.

Comment: In my old field, those students *still suppported by faculty* (those who were not counseled to go to industry instead) have pretty much a 100% placement rate. In the somewhat rare case of people failing in a first attempt, senior (famous) faculty tends to put in some calls, which resulted in jobs for everyone during my entire time in the program. I'd think CS at a top school (top 5? top 10?) will be similar.

Comment: @gnometorule what field are you in that has a virtually 100% placement rate

Comment: @user2562609: That was at a business school, across all 7 or so sub-fields (economics, finance, ..., marketing). Of course that's after losing about 50% along the way compared to numbers on day one (drop-outs, or counseled out); and some - like me - end up *preferring* to go to industry. It's among those making it to the job market, and wanting to be placed (that's almost all though). It was the same though at dptmts I was familiar with (e.g., stats).

Comment: This depends on too many factors for any single answer to be meaningful.

Comment: What do you mean by "fail"? Many PhD graduates decide to work outside academia -- is that "simply failing to find an academic job"? If so, that's a terrible definition of "fail"; if not, it's hard to imagine how one would collect the data you're looking for.